# Remove NaT values while inserting data into mongo using pymongo

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, pymongo

Have a df with values

```
name    date

tom    2019-12-10 07:44:03.733
mark   NaT
```

if i try this :

```
data = df.to_dict("records")

mydb.test.insert_many(data)
```

I'm getting this error :

`ValueError: NaTType does not support utcoffset`

How to send this data to mongodb without NaT and keeping the column empty without converting to string.

expected data in mongodb :

```
{
_id:ObjectId(5db012b123a2a1cabcc12345),
name:tom,
date:2019-10-23T10:55:50.569+00:00
}


{
_id:ObjectId(5db012b123a2a1cabcc12346),
name:mark
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert `NaT` to `None`, like below:

If your `df['date']` is not a `datetime` column, convert it into one.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['date'] = df['date'].astype(object).where(df['date'].notnull(), None)
```

Then you can insert this in `mongo`.

Comment: i'm getting  `date:null` in mongo

Comment: Yes, for that record you will get `date` as `null` in mongo. Database represents `None` as  `null`.